# How do i create a google places like API in Nodejs using express

Tags: regex, node.js, google-maps, express, restify

I am trying to create a RESTful service in Node.js using express like the Google places API which should be in the following format.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%1,%2&radius=%3&name=%4&key=AIzaSyAh4t-qlMYrxnk0XF0Yiu9ZXVFDNfPTCFs

Its very unlike the standard way of passing params to an express app which expects in the following format /google/nearbysearch/place/:location=%1,%2/radius/:radius=%3 and etc..

The challenge here is how to use express and decrypt the response to easily parsing the params to a call. I did extensive research but could not find any links on google or stackOverflow. Thanks for the help.

I hear and have checked out restify (http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) where it allows to pass regex strings to the request url. How do they achieve such in Node.js (solutions without using express will also be helpful).

Thanks
Anurag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Connect.js and Express.js middlware to parse the incoming query string and body conveniently. You can go to the official website http://expressjs.com or look at my examples http://expressjsguide.com and http://webapplog.com.

It's possible to parse without them, but you'll have to write more code (look at the core modules at http://nodejs.org/api).